# Displaying data from an array into labels and text areas (SQLite, iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, sqlite

I was reading tutorials for SQLite data reading and they all appear to use tables for displaying the data and I was wondering if anyone had an example of getting data into an array and displaying one database column in a label and another in a text area.

Any help would be great,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You still need to use a tableView. But you'll need to customize it so that it appears to the user that there is one column solely for labels, and another column solely for text areas.

Besides, I don't think your question has much to do with SQLite. It appears to be more about UI pattern things.